# Resources not found with CDI/Weld JAX-RS/RESTEasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi, resteasy, weld

I try to setup CDI/Weld and JAX-RS/RESTEasy on Netty in a Java SE environment, but all I get is the following exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8000/
```

My project has the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-netty4</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I placed a beans.xml file in the src/main/resources/META-INF directory to enable CDI.

The code to start netty:

```
@Singleton
public class App {

  private static NettyJaxrsServer netty;

  public void printHello(
          @Observes ContainerInitialized event,
          @Parameters List<String> parameters) 
          throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Starting Netty ...");
    ResteasyDeployment deployment = new ResteasyDeployment();
    netty = new NettyJaxrsServer();
    netty.setDeployment(deployment);
    netty.setPort(8000);
    netty.setRootResourcePath("");
    netty.setSecurityDomain(null);
    netty.start();
  }
```

The example resource looks like this:

```
@Path("/hi") // tried "/" too
public class Index {

  @GET
  public String get() {
    return "Hi!";
  }
}
```

Since all of this didn't work, I added an application class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class DemoApplication  extends Application {
  // empty
}
```

But the error message is still the same.

What is missing? How can I setup Weld and RESTEasy?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this link?  [Tomcat 7, Weld, RESTEasy not Scanning JARs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546158/tomcat-7-weld-resteasy-not-scanning-jars)

It says that you should put `beans.xml` in WEB-INF instead of META-INF.